# C# Image Resizer with Canvas Handler

Tags: c#, image, canvas, resize

I'm incredibly new to C# (just started today)

I need to be able to make a C# Image resizer with a canvas handler. For example a 500 x 500 image needs to retain its aspect ration. it will be getting resized to 1024x500. To do this it will remain 500x500 but then fill the rest of the space with white space (the canvas).

I will also be resizing the same original image to 300 x 500, where the image will again retain its 1:1 ration and be resized to 300x300 and the remaining space again used as canvas white space.

Can anybody help me to produce a C# console application for this, that I can understand?

Here is what I have managed to find that I could reasonably understand (due to nice commenting).

What I find with code is that I can read it, but when it comes to me actually writing some I just fall apart. I mainly do HTML and CSS. Starting to branch out into JQuery and C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ImageResizer
{

    class ImageResize
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        public void ResizeImage(string OriginalFile, string NewFile, int NewWidth, int MaxHeight, bool OnlyResizeIfWider)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OriginalFile);

            // Prevent using images internal thumbnail

            FullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

            FullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

            if (OnlyResizeIfWider)
                {

                    if (FullsizeImage.Width <= NewWidth)
                {
                NewWidth = FullsizeImage.Width;
                }
                }

            int NewHeight = FullsizeImage.Height * NewWidth / FullsizeImage.Width;
            if (NewHeight > MaxHeight)
            {
            // Resize with height instead
                NewWidth = FullsizeImage.Width * MaxHeight / FullsizeImage.Height;
                NewHeight = MaxHeight;
            }
            System.Drawing.Image NewImage = FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(NewWidth, NewHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);

            // Clear handle to original file so that we can overwrite it if necessary
            FullsizeImage.Dispose();

            // Save resized picture
        NewImage.Save(NewFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're asking how to display an image in a console application then you can't. But, if you're using WinForms or WPF then you can use a fixed height but auto for width

Comment: Try something yourself first and come back, when you have trouble. This is how [SO](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) works.

Comment: @DaveRook Well, actually you could, but the resolution would suck.

Comment: I'm asking how to run a batch of images through a console application to resize the resolutions. So that I have a copy of the new resized images in a folder in a nearby directory.

Comment: @GrantThomas - Really? A console application can display images? +1 I had no idea this possible

Comment: @MarcCossins So what have you tried?

Comment: @MarcCossins - Update your question to reflect this is what you want as your comment is actually clearer than your original question IMO. Either way, you need to ask specific points - We can't just write the code for you, it's about you trying it yourself, getting stuck and we can help with that part

Comment: I have managed to find a piece of code from the internet. I can almost understand it. But I'm having difficulty understanding what I need to edit (IE file URL's etc, should I post what I have found on this thread?)

Comment: Edited my original post, apologies

Comment: Would this be easier to try and build using a Form instead of the console application?

Answer (score 1):

Try To Go For This>>

```
private void resizeImage(string path, string originalFilename, 
                     /* note changed names */
                     int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight, 
                     /* new */
                     int originalWidth, int originalHeight)
{
    Image image = Image.FromFile(path + originalFilename);

    System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = 
        new Bitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight); // changed parm names
    System.Drawing.Graphics graphic = 
                 System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail);

    graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

    /* ------------------ new code --------------- */

    // Figure out the ratio
    double ratioX = (double) canvasWidth / (double) originalWidth;
    double ratioY = (double) canvasHeight / (double) originalHeight;
    // use whichever multiplier is smaller
    double ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY;

    // now we can get the new height and width
    int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(originalHeight * ratio);
    int newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(originalWidth * ratio);

    // Now calculate the X,Y position of the upper-left corner 
    // (one of these will always be zero)
    int posX = Convert.ToInt32((canvasWidth - (originalWidth * ratio)) / 2);
    int posY = Convert.ToInt32((canvasHeight - (originalHeight * ratio)) / 2);

    graphic.Clear(Color.White); // white padding
    graphic.DrawImage(image, posX, posY, newWidth, newHeight);

    /* ------------- end new code ---------------- */

    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo[] info =
                     ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
    encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality,
                     100L);            
    thumbnail.Save(path + width + "." + originalFilename, info[1], 
                     encoderParameters);
}
```

Comment: See I can read that and understand it. But in all honesty I don't know how it works specifically? If that makes sense. IE I dont know how I'd link in my file directory to edit my images.